# Show Fancybox once per session on a specific day

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to show a Fancybox on page load and only once per visit. So far so good... 
What I further try to do is show this Fancybox only on Sundays every week. So what I did  is a simple check if the day is Sunday and if so then trigger the autostart. Unfortunately it gives me an error saying `TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined`.

I can't get rid of this error and I don't know where it comes from.

My complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openFancy(){
    var d = new Date($(this).val());
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    if(curr_date == 0){ // 0 = sundays
      setTimeout( function(){
        $('#autoStart').trigger('click');
      },500);
    }
  }

  function dontShow(){

    var cookieDays= '7'
    $.fancybox.close();
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: +cookieDays }); // expiration in 30 days
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
      return false;
    } else {
      openFancy();
    }
    $('#autoStart').fancybox({
      autoSize: false,
      height:340,
      width:340,
      type: 'inline'
    });
  });
    </script>
```

Can anybody help me with this? Or give some directions? Thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getDate(); returns the day of the month. getDay(); returns the day of the week.